# Not able to train a simple Char RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been working on a vanilla char rnn in tensorflow. I am not able it to produce any thing sensible even after training it a couple of hours. The code is tf version of Keras code from Chollet's Deep learning with python[Github](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/8.1-text-generation-with-lstm.ipynb)
I tried playing around with hyper params without much success. Chollet mentioned in the book that the model produced good output after 80 epochs. I have able to get anything resonable after 50K+ epochs :( Curious if there is something I missed while converting this code to tensorflow.

```
n_layers = 1
num_units = 128
batch_size = 150
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, maxlen, len(unique_chars)], name="Placeholder_X")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None, len(unique_chars)], name="Placeholder_Y")

lstm_cells = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=num_units) for layer in range(n_layers)]
multi_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_cells)
outputs, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)

top_layer_h_state = current_state[-1][1]
logits = tf.layers.dense(top_layer_h_state, len(unique_chars), name="softmax")
xentropy=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Sampling Code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    saver.restore(sess, model_name)
    # Output some data
    start_index = random.randint(0, len(text) - maxlen - 1)
    generated_text = text[start_index: start_index + maxlen]
    print("Seed: ", generated_text)
    final_string = ""
    sampled = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(unique_chars)))

    for i in range(50):
        for t, char in enumerate(generated_text):
            sampled[0, t, char_to_idx[char]] = 1.
        preds_eval = sess.run([pred], feed_dict={X: sampled})
        preds=preds_eval[0][0]            
        next_index = sample(preds, 0.5) 
        next_char = unique_chars[next_index]
        generated_text += next_char
        final_string += next_char
        generated_text = generated_text[1:]
    print("New String: " , final_string)
```

Sample Input Seed:   is,
as is generally acknowledged nowadays, no better sopori

Input generation:

```
maxlen = 60
step = 3 
sentences = []
next_chars = []

for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
    sentences.append(text[i:i + maxlen])
    next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])

unique_chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
char_to_idx = dict((char, unique_chars.index(char)) for char in unique_chars)


data_X = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(unique_chars)), dtype=np.float32)

data_Y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(unique_chars)), dtype=np.int64)
for idx, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        data_X[idx, t, char_to_idx[char]] = 1
    data_Y[idx, char_to_idx[next_chars[idx]]] = 1
```

Output from the model: vatsoéätlæéättire

Comment: updated to show input generation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a language model. I didn't read your entire code carefully. Just from the first part I noticed a couple of things. Why is your placeholder for `x` of type `tf.float32` instead of integers? More importantly, why is the shape of `y` equal to batch size by vocab size? It should be batch_size by max_len -1 by vocab_size. In a language model you are always trying to predict the next character at every step. It's not a good way to train it to read a whole sequence of characters and then just predict one more at the end.

Comment: * I was getting type errors if input is int32.    For the shape of y, this is onehot encoded vector. The  model only predicts the next character in sequence. i.e X="abc" Y="d"

Comment: Typically, the way we train language models is that it would be predicting the "b" after seeing "a", predicting "c" after seeing "ab" and predicting "d" after seeing "abc". That gives it a lot more signal to train from.